# How to get carousel to be responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, swipe

How to activate the plugin is responsive carousel ONLY WHEN size less than 1024px width. But if more than 1024px then inactive. Example i use

```
$(window).bind("load resize", function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width <= 1024) {
        $("#product-item").addClass("owl-carousel").addClass("owl-theme");
    } else {
        $("#product-item").removeClass("owl-carousel").removeClass("owl-theme");
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zgnkn3hw/6/. When I use the code above, still active.
Although I've removeClass `owl-owl-themed carousel-loaded owl owl-drag`, but still can be shifted. because `owl-item` and `owl-stage` cant be eliminated, such as `$(".product-item").removeAttr("style")`

**UPDATE QUESTION**

How when i press button. `class 1 and 2` be removed but `class 3` still show

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $(".1").remove();
  $(".2").remove();
  $(".3").still(); /* still alive */
});

<button>Button</button>
<span class="1">
        <span class="2">
            <span class="3">
            </span>
        </span>
</span>
```

To Be

```
<button>Button</button>
<span class="3">
</span>
```

because `class 1 and 2` is `owl-item` and `owl-stage`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem of your code is not class things, but the way jsfiddle generating code.

The following code it generated by jsfiddle.

```
window.onload=function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            margin: 10,
            autoHeight: true
        });
     })


    $(window).bind("load resize", function() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        console.log(width);
        if (width <= 1024) {
            $("#product-item").addClass("owl-carousel").addClass("owl-theme");
        } else {
            $("#product-item").removeClass("owl-carousel").removeClass("owl-theme");
        }
    });
}
```

Your "load" event listener is in a "onload" callback, so its callback can't be called at beginning. 
Try to resize the window yourself you may find the code actually works.

Update:

```js
$("button").click(function() {  
  $(".b").unwrap();
  $(".c").unwrap();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button</button>
<span class="a">
        <span class="b">
            <span class="c">
            </span>
</span>
</span>
```

Comment: @natasha you want to remove dom or just remove class?

Comment: maybe the only way just removeClass

Comment: I updated the answer. Is it what u want? If not, I can't really understand what u want. It's seems that u thought the "removeClass" doesn't work. Maybe u can try to print some log to ensure the methods are actually called.